# Sum $\dfrac{1}{ 8 + 2x^2}$

Tags: calculus, summation

Here's another one from my gf's calc 2 midterm.
The professor provided an answer key but his work doesn't make sense.
Attached is the work I did to do the problem, and his work from the answer key.
Specifically, his last steps of integration don't quite seem to make sense to me.
Any insight would be appreciated. 
Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inIsd.jpg)

Comment: This is not clear.  A sum is not an integral.

Comment: Neither of the answers given appear to be correct. I'd use the Poisson summation formula to solve this.

Comment: You can integrate the sum to find if the series converges or not, other then that the result obtain from the integration isn't necessarily equal to the sum....

Comment: @Alex Hal Interesting. I forgot that the integral test is only a test for convergence.

Comment: Wolfram gives the sum as $(2\pi\coth(2\pi)-1)/16$.

Comment: @MichaelRomeroJr. what was the question that was asked relating to this sum?

Answer (score 1):

But, notice that when using the integral test, $\sum a_n $ is not equal $\int f(n)$ where $a_n = f(n)$. It is just an approximation that only works as long as $f'(x) < 0$ on $[a, \infty)$ for some $a$. Also, $f$ better be positive and continuous. In conclusion, both yours and your professor solution may not
 be correct